# What happens when multiple processes try to write the same file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Due to a limitation of a 3rd party library, I need to use a file with a static name. What happens in Rails if multiple users are trying to write to that file at the same time? EACCESS error?

Is there a way I could circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the Ruby level, what will happen if multiple processes try to write to the file depends on how the library uses the file: whether and how it locks the file before opening it and what mode it opens the file in. It might just work, it might raise an error, or (most likely, if the library does nothing to handle this situation) multiple writers might silently interleave writes with one another in a way that could corrupt the file, or the last writer might win.

At the Rails level, it depends on how you run Rails. If you run a single, normally configured Rails instance on a given server, you won't have any problems, since Rails itself is single-threaded by default. If you run multiple Rails instances (presumably controlled by an application server like Passenger or unicorn) you might have problems.

Assuming the library doesn't handle multiple writers for you, you can work around it in a couple of ways:

- Run only one instance of your Rails app on each server (or docker container or chrooted environment).
- Fork the library and change it to include the process ID in the file name. That's what I'd do.